# Vuetify 3 Specify heigh and text size of list items in autocomplete/select

Tags: vuetifyjs3

I think that the list items in the select/autocomplete are taking up way too much space.
I can't figure out the css classes used for the list items.
Ideally I would set this in a global css...

Has anyone figured out how to achieve more "compact looking" listitems in the select/autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see if you prefer the look when just changing props.

```html
<v-autocomplete
  :items="items"
  :item-props="itemProps"
></v-autocomplete>
```

```js
function itemProps(item) {
  return {
    density: 'compact' // 'default' | 'comfortable' | 'compact'
  }
}
```

For more exact control, the quickest way to change the height and font size would be to target these two classes:

```css
.v-list-item {
  min-height: 10px !important;
}
.v-list-item-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

Since these are actually targeting v-list classes, the above CSS will affect not just v-autocomplete but any other v-list, v-menu, v-select, etc. To target just autocompletes, you need to add a class to the dropdown overlay that you can then add to the CSS selector

```html
<v-autocomplete
  :items="items"
  :menu-props="{
    contentClass: 'autocomplete-overlay'
  }"
></v-autocomplete>
```

```css
.autocomplete-overlay .v-list-item {
  min-height: 10px !important;
}
.autocomplete-overlay .v-list-item-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed! <3